# Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$, does this inequality holds $\frac{a}{na + kb} + \frac{b}{nb+kc} + \frac{c}{nc + ka} \ge \frac{3}{k+n}$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, arithmetic, roots

Does the following statement/inequality holds for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$?

$$\frac{a}{na + kb} + \frac{b}{nb+kc} + \frac{c}{nc + ka} \ge \frac{3}{k+n}$$

---

I've been thinking for hours and I couldn't find a solution to this inequality. I tried  to use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for fraction:

$$\frac{x^2}{a} + \frac{y^2}{b} + \frac{z^2}{c} \ge \frac{(z+x+y)^2}{a+b+c}$$

But I only get:

$$LHS \ge \frac{(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c})^2}{(n+k)(a+b+c)}$$

And then I can't prove that:

$$(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c})^2 \ge 3(a+b+c)$$
$$a + b + c + 2\sqrt{ab} + 2\sqrt{ac} + 2\sqrt{bc} \ge 3(a+b+c)$$
$$\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{ac} + \sqrt{bc} \ge a+b+c$$

Which simplifyies to:

$$\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}) + \sqrt{b}(\sqrt{c} - \sqrt{b}) + \sqrt{c}(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{c}) \ge 0$$

But if $a\neq b \neq c$, one of the terms must be negative, so nothing here.

And at last I plug it into Wolfram Alpha, and for some random numbers $n$ and $k$ it's true. I wonder maybe the fact that the LHS is cyclic we make the LHS to have minimal values when $a=b=c$?

Comment: For reals, $(x+y+z)^2 \le 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ by a simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz, so that approach won't work...

Comment: Any other method to solve it? It's obvious that the equality holds for $a=b=c$, so probaly finding a expression that's smaller than LHS and greater than RHS won't be easy.

Maybe some direct comparison or transformation?

Comment: I am not sure if your inequality actually holds.  e.g. take $(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 1)$ and $(k, n) = (1, 2)$.  I get LHS $= \frac{59}{60} < 1 =$ RHS. Perhaps you need some additional conditions.

Comment: @Macavity Originally it was a inequality when $(k,n) = (4,5)$, but also I wasn't able to solve it. Then trying for different values it worked, but as you said $(1,2)$ is counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

By applying CBS is obtained

$$\frac{a^2}{na^2+kab} + \frac{b^2}{nb^2+kbc} + \frac{c^2}{nc^2+kca} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{n(a^2+b^2+c^2)+k(ab+bc+ca)}.$$

But

$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{n(a^2+b^2+c^2)+k(ab+bc+ca)}\ge \frac{3}{n+k}$$

is equivalent to

$$(k-2n)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\ge 0$$

which is true under the additional condition

$$k\ge2n.$$

Comment: But that says that for $n=4$ and $k=5$, the inequality will not hold, but the problem says prove it.

Comment: Can you prove it for $n=4$ and $k=5$? Using your method I get:

$$ab + bc + ba >= a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

which is obviously wrong. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n,k\in\mathbb R^+$.

**Necessary condition**.- Notice that LHS-RHS is equal to $$\frac{(c-1)^2k(k-n)}{(k+n)(kc+n)(k+nc)}$$ for $a=1,b=1$.  Therefore it is mandatory that $k\geq n$ for the inequality to hold.

**Sufficient condition**.- ...

Answer (score 0):

If $k\ge 2n$ then by CS, the inequality is true as proved by @medicu. If $k<2n$, strictly, then letting $a\to 0$, we have

$$\frac{b}{nb+kc} \ge \frac{3}{k+n}-\frac{1}{n}$$

But this is not true because the right hand side is positive, while we can make the left hand side goes to zero when $c\to \infty$.

So the necessary and sufficient condition is $k\ge 2n$.